# Find opposite numbers and replace them with NA

Tags: r, na

Assume that I have this dataset

```
x   y
na  100
na   na
na   na
na   200
-100   na
200   100
500   1000
600   20000
na    200
100    -1000
1000    na
na      1000
-200    -100
0        na
300     0
na     -200
-300    na
na      0
```

well i want to replace with NA the opposite values without loosing the rows, the desired output would be

```
x   y
na  100
na   na
na   na
na   NA
NA   na
NA   NA
500   NA
600   20000
na    200
NA    NA
1000    na
na      1000
NA    NA
0        na
NA     0
na     NA
NA    na
na      0
```

For example if in my dataset but on the same column exist two opposite numbers i want to replace both of them with NA. If i have -100 and +100 replace them with NA.

Comment: What is now different to your question from yesterday? [Replace with NA the opposite values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68456577/10488504)

Comment: Appears to be somewhat underspecified, why one +100 and one +1000 in `y` have been removed and one left? If there are more instances of the same number, does it matter which one gets removed?

Comment: for some reason closed this one and did not accept answers!

Comment: Obviously you remove pairwise. But why do you once start from beginning (200 in column y) and once from end (100 in column y)?

Comment: Could you explain the question again? It's very difficult to understand what you mean. "i want to replace with NA the opposite values without loosing the rows". What is the opposite value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `function` making iteratively the changes:

```
f <- function(y) {
  for(i in 1:(length(y)-1)) {
    for(j in (i+1):length(y)) {
      if(!is.na(y[i]) & !is.na(y[j]) & y[i] != 0 & y[i] == -y[j]) {
        y[c(i,j)] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  y
}

x[] <- lapply(x, f)

x
#      x     y
#1    NA    NA
#2    NA    NA
#3    NA    NA
#4    NA    NA
#5    NA    NA
#6    NA   100
#7   500    NA
#8   600 20000
#9    NA   200
#10   NA    NA
#11 1000    NA
#12   NA  1000
#13   NA    NA
#14    0    NA
#15   NA     0
#16   NA    NA
#17   NA    NA
#18   NA     0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, -100, 200, 500, 600, NA, 
100, 1000, NA, -200, 0, 300, NA, -300, NA), y = c(100, NA, NA, 
200, NA, 100, 1000, 20000, 200, -1000, NA, 1000, -100, NA, 0, 
-200, NA, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this as data example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("na",-100,100,200,500,-200,"na"),
                 y = c("na","na",300,-300,500,-400,"na"))
     x    y
1   na   na
2 -100   na
3  100  300
4  200 -300
5  500  500
6 -200 -400
7   na   na
```

Then we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
output <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == "na", NA, .))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. %in% -., NA, .)))
```

Which results in:

```
    x    y
1  NA   NA
2  NA   NA
3  NA   NA
4  NA   NA
5 500  500
6  NA -400
7  NA   NA
```

Edit: To keep the rep. That's kind of tricky, there should be better solution, but it works:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == "na", NA, .))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(count_x = 1:n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(count_y = 1:n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(x, ~ifelse(. %in% -. & count_x == 1, NA, .))) %>% 
  mutate(across(y, ~ifelse(. %in% -. & count_y == 1, NA, .))) %>% 
  select(-count_x, -count_y)
```

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("na",-100,100,200,500,-200,100,"na"),
                 y = c("na","na",300,-300,300,-400,300,"na"))
     x    y
1   na   na
2 -100   na
3  100  300
4  200 -300
5  500  300
6 -200 -400
7  100  300
8   na   na
```

Output:

```
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA
2    NA    NA
3    NA    NA
4    NA    NA
5   500   300
6    NA  -400
7   100   300
8    NA    NA
```

Comment: That is a great idea but it deletes me double same numbers. For example if I have in my data set 100,200,-100,-200,200 I want it to be NA,NA,NA,NA,200. This function now returns NA,NA,NA,NA,NA